# Opening controller view two times after search

Tags: ios

I was trying to understand passing data between controllers. I'm displaying a tableview with search and navigation bar. When I select one of the rows, it opens another controller view with detailed informations. However if I select after making a search, it opens the same detailed controller view two times.

[image]
[image]

Here is my row selection code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showRecipeDetail" sender: self];
}


 }
```

What might the problem be?

Comment: have you do anything in :
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `segue` on cell selection you shouldn't write
`if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showRecipeDetail" sender: self];
}`

If you need to push difference `VC` you should add segue from VC to VC, not from `UITableViewCell`.
And use:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showRecipeDetail" sender: self];
}
else
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showDifferentVC" sender: self];
}

 }
```

Comment: hmm I got it. I made segue on cell selection. When I removed disSelect fucntion, it worked. When I call this function, am I calling segue 2 times?

Comment: @AhmetTanakol if you call  [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showRecipeDetail" sender: self]; in `DidSelectRow` you call segue 2 times.